# in Disney's Gargoyles, if there are only 3 known races (Gargoyles, Humans and Oberon's Children) what of the other legendary beings?

Tags: magical-creatures, gargoyles-1994

Disney's *Gargoyles* intruded Oberon, the Fairy King, as ostensibly the "source" of most magic in the world. By this, I mean it's his "Children" which became beings of incredible legend, from haunting spirits like the Banshee, to demi-immortals like Merlin, to legendary trickster spirits in various tribal legends (Raven, Coyote, Anansi) to full on "Gods" such as Odin. Most seemed to share a weakness to iron, but other than that, near limitless power. This is especially true in the case of the "God tier" beings; even weakened, Odin was shown to have full on weather control and transformation.

However, there are many beings, from Vampires and werewolves, to other pantheons of Gods, such as the Asian, Greek, Polynesian and others, as well as high class demons, which were never seen or even mentioned (at least, in the cartoon.) This implies that Oberon, though powerful, is **not** the *only* "Magical well spring" of earth, and other equal powers may well exist. From this we can infer a few  things:

1. The other legends may be just myths... but in this  world where *Ghosts* exist, that's very uncertain. This is especially so because the Captain's Ghost (gargoyle leader Goliath's former human friend) ascended to another plain of existence, and no "earthly" magic [Oberon's domain] could hold him back.
2. The first statement make sense because had they too been Oberon's children, *Some* representatives from those pantheons would have been present for the Gathering.
3. For an "All powerful" being, Oberon *himself* was susceptible to iron, and many other Divinities would not have this weakness.

I know that there were 2 comic series (one current, one that occurred during the show's original run), and was wondering:

**Did any subsidiary material elucidate on the existence of other supernatural races *outside* of Oberon's Children?**

This could be anything from monsters of folk lore to other high level beings, such a Divinities and Demons?

The closest I can remember were the "New Olympians", but it seems these *were* distantly related to Oberon somehow.

Comment: Does Nokkar count? https://gargoyles.fandom.com/wiki/Nokkar

Comment: Oberon was the leader/king of the "Third Race". The Third Race were known as Oberons Children, because he was their leader, not because they were his literal children. Prior to Oberon being King, they were ruled by his mother Mab and known as the Children of Mab.